# JSF 1.2 Add Parameter to Redirect Request

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

i use Jsf 1.2 and have navigation rule with redirect, my question is how to add request parameters to view redirected

Comment: This looks like useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605238/how-do-you-pass-view-parameters-when-navigating-from-an-action-in-jsf2

Comment: @Omar that works since JSF 2. OP's question is for JSF 1.2.

Comment: Thanks, i see the solucion in JSF 2, but i dont know if exists a similar feature to JSSF 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible using navigation rules in JSF 1.x. Use `ExternalContext#redirect()` instead.

```
public void action() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String url = ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/page.jsf?someparam=" + URLEncoder.encode(someparam, "UTF-8");
    ec.redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: Instead of appending a new param as string to url, can I add query param key & value programatically through API?

Comment: @user2918640: You can. JSF only doesn't offer a public URL builder API. JSF utility library OmniFaces has a convenience `Faces#redirect()` method which automatically prepends context path and URL-encodes params.

Comment: But how do I do it in primefaces? Copy OmniFaces source? I want to safely add params to a url which may already be containing a parameter.

Comment: OmniFaces is not a component library. It is an utility library which can be used with any component library. Even more, OmniFaces showcase application uses PrimeFaces.