# JSF add parameter from bean

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I working with JSF 2.1 and primefaces 6.0.
I have a commandButton in page A like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="GO" action="#{indexBB.clickSearchButton}" />
```

In the backingbean function:

```
public String clickSearchButton() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("dateini", dateFormat.format(dateIni));
return "B?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

In page B I try to recover the values but the map is empty and the just created parameter is no longer there:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Map<String,Object> parameterMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    if(parameterMap.get("dateini") != null ){
        //assign the value
    }
}
```

How could I send a parameter from the backingbean and recover it correctly in next page?
I have taken a look at some other answer here with no result, like for example:

[How to add request parameter in jsf2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111649/how-to-add-request-parameter-in-jsf2)

I don't want to use a 'f:param' or something like that.

May someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure but try return "B?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true"

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. When I check the parameter value in page B it is still NULL...

Comment: The question indicated as duplicated has a good answer:
public String clickSearchButton() {
    return "B?faces-redirect=true&word=" + URLEncoder.encode(inidate, "UTF-8");
}